# Detect if child Runtime has exited

Tags: java

I want to close the parent process when the child Runtime has been exited. How do I do this?

I've tried the following:

```
Runtime x = Runtime.getRuntime();
x.addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    public void run(){
            System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

But after `x.exec()` is called and the child process is killed, the parent process doesn't exit.

```
Runtime x = Runtime.getRuntime();
x.addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
x.exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+s+"\" & start cmd.exe /k \"java -jar autoPoke.jar\""); 
// s is a String of a directory
// the above line does work
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you would need to set some flag and another thread that watches for that flag switch to kill parent Runtime

Comment: The shutdown hook is called in response to the JVM termination requests, you should not be calling `System.exit` as the JVM is already in throws exiting...

Comment: what is the purpose of this "parent process"?

Comment: The parent process allows the executable jar file to be opened in a cmd window and restarted every so often.

Comment: Could `Runtime.wait()` work?